# Start android application on network connection established

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to start an **android application** when a network connection is established? I want to start a service once a network connection is established, without the application being open beforehand. I need this service to keep running at all times in the background once there's a network connection, even if the application is closed.

Perhaps something similar to how an application may be started on boot?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: A [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a BroadcastReceiver that will listen to network state changes and checks if there is internet, then starts your app.
Here you are the broadcast

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        if (isOnline()) {
            // if the internet is working, start the main activity or any activity you want
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }

    private boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

add those permissions to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and add it to the manifest inside application tag "just add your package name before the class name"

```
<receiver
        android:name="add your package name here.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try monitoring the changes in connectivity explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

You can use a `STICKY SERVICE` so that service is always running in the background. To keep the service running, you can also consider using Wake Locks. But that may drain the battery much faster.